# Need PHP or Regex script for matching URL's

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I'm changing all the URL's on my websites to lower case. I'm also replacing all the underscores with dashes. So the URL /World/New_York would become /world/new-york.

However, I don't want to lose traffic from links that are still pointing to /World/New_York, so I'd like that link to work as well. As I understand it, I can use an Apache file to automatically change the URL's in the browser to the correct format (lower case).

So what I want to do right now is simply make sure that all relevant links are accepted, 1) regardless of case and 2) regardless of whether words are separated by _, - or a simple space...

/world/new-york
/World/New-York
/WORLD/New York
/wORld/new_YORK

All of the above URL's should be accepted, because 1) they all have the same characters, and 2) the words are separated by a dash, underscore or space.

In my PHP code, the URL is represented by the value $MyURL. So if you visit MySite/world/new-york, $MyURL = new-york, where new-york is a MySQL database value.

So I think what I need to do is create a script that says $MyURL = 1) the database value, or 2) the database value with an allowance for alternate case values, and/or 3) the database value with the dash replaced by an underscore or space. I would then insert this script before my page display query (below).

Can anyone tell me how to write such a script using either PHP or regular expression?

```
$sql= "SELECT COUNT(URL) AS num FROM orgs
WHERE URL = :MyURL";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':MyURL',$MyURL,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$Total = $stmt->fetch();
```

---

@ Shahar...

Below is some code from one of my .htaccess files, where I inserted your code...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^test\.htm$ test.php [L]
Options -MultiViews

#Your suggested rule...
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /${lower:$1}

php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off

RewriteRule ^topics/([a-zA-Z0-9()_/-]+)/?$ topics/index.php?topic=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^world/([a-zA-Z0-9()_/-]+)/?$ world/index.php?area=$1 [L]
```

But when I type in px/Topics/Ethics, I get a NOT FOUND error. When I change it to px/topics/Ethics or px/topics/ethics it works. However, I'd like Ethics to change to ethics.

One of my concerns is statistics. I don't want to check my daily statistics and see 16 hits for Topics/Ethics, 13 for topics/Ethics and 3 for topics/ethics. Rather, I'd like to see 32 hits for topics/ethics. Apache is way over my head, though. ;)

Comment: You didn't *apply* the rule. You're supposed to use `${lower:$1}`. Also, `px/Topics` isn't found because you defined the rewrite rule to `topics` and not to the entire server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to convert the URL's to lowercase automatically, use `mod_rewrite`. This is what you need to add:

```
RewriteMap lower int:tolower
RewriteRule  ^([^/]+)/?$  yourdir/${lower:$1}
```

You didn't specify what `yourdir` was... Or just do: `RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /${lower:$1}`.

Using PHP, you can just do `strtolower()`. Although, I don't quite understand why. I believe MySQL searches are case-insensative.

**EDIT:** Also, for the replacing part, I think this should work:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\_(.*)$ $1\-$2
RewriteRule ^(.*)\%20(.*)$ $1\-$2
```

The first will replace `_` with `-`, the second will replace space (`$20`) with `-`.

Comment: You're a mind reader! That was going to be my second question (for another thread) - after I've made sure all relevant URL's are accepted, how do I make all those variations default to lower case with dashes?

But I'm confused. Let me edit my original post with my mod_rewrite question so I can format it properly...

Comment: @DavidBlomstrom Oh yeah, I missed that second part about replacing the spaces & `_`. Alright I'll see your edited post and then edit mine.

Comment: Sorry, I think I must have made a mistake in my explanation. I tried your revised rules in another .htaccess file and it works - though not in the way I intended. I can now display mysite/world/new_york or mysite/world/new-york (with an underscore or dash). However, my goal is to create a script that accepts both variations (as well as variations with upper case letters) but then defaults to mysite/world/new-york. A good example is Wikipedia. If you type in wikipedia/en/New York, the URL will default to wikipedia/en/New_York. But I want my URL's to default to lower case characters + dashes.

Comment: @DavidBlomstrom Oh. That's right, because `mod_rewrite` doesn't change the actual URL but redirects to another. That's a good question. I think websites like Wikipedia or even SO (try changing something in the URL, it will change back when you press enter) have a different code that automatically makes it lowercase/changes the characters to dashes. It's weird, I have it on my website (all the spaces change to `-`), but I don't remember what I did...